# How to init login page as home in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm learning CakePHP and i want to know how to init login page as home.

Currently my system is like that.

root `/`
Users `controller`
login `method`

to make login i browser to `localhost/users/login` but i need to know how to run in `localhost/` or `localhost/login`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in your routes.php

```
$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
```

Comment: if i set the method as _login i can call it in the route?

Comment: What happens when you try it?